# Peek at next element in a Tree set using an iterator

Tags: java, data-structures

I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish this, or if there are alternative data structures. It has to be sorted, without duplicates, and have an iterator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`TreeSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) has an [`iterator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#iterator()), is sorted, won't have duplicates, and is able to see the next higher element by using [`higher`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#higher(E)).

For example:

```
TreeSet<Integer> ts = new TreeSet<Integer>();
ts.add(1);
ts.add(4);
ts.add(4);
ts.add(3);

for (Integer i : ts) {
  System.out.println("current: " + i + " next:  " + ts.higher(i));
}
```

The output is:

```
current: 1  next: 3
current: 3  next: 4
current: 4  next: null
```

Comment: higher()! Good find (or memory)! I was hunting around for something like ListIterator for Sets.

Comment: It was a find -- I haven't used TreeSet before -- those API Specifications come in handy :)

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about higher. I guess I have to keep the current element in memory as that seems to be the only way to do it.

Comment: This is only available in Java 1.6 and later by the way